# Can't open settings window in uniface debugger

Tags: debugging, uniface

I can't open the settings windows in the debugger of uniface 9.7 any more.

If i click on the menu "Settings" nothing happens.

[see debugger settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nxPA.png)

Have someone an idea what i can do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the uniface forum from the user 'Iain Sharp' that works for me.

"Try resetting the app layout.
Click the uniface icon on the very top left of the debugger window, then settings then go to the state tab, and tick "Delete current layout.....".
Then close out of the debugger, and try again." (Iain Sharp)

See here: [In the debugger enviroment the 'Settings' window can't be open](https://community.rocketsoftware.com/forums/forum-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=bb68ebaf-a387-48df-9c8a-a3ff341a6129&CommunityKey=edb92b7f-cb45-44f3-9782-c48a111007d6&tab=digestviewer#bmfd63f23a-26d8-41cd-99f9-44e82e0a2a89)

Answer (score 0):

You must have made it too small by acciden and now you cannot resize it anymore.
Use regedit to delete the settings for the uniface debugger window/pane sizes.

Comment: Thank you, i found an answer in the uniface forum. See my answer from Nov 17 2021.